# How to use multiple textures on a single vertex buffer in Apple Metal API?

Tags: textures, shader, gpu, texture-mapping, metal

Is there a Metal API feature which can let me use multiple textures mapped to the same vertex buffer?

Some experiments I did to achieve that was to merge the textures into one entity (only the coordinates, using the same mipmap), but I got not perfect result:

[image]

Comment: So you want two `MTLTexture`s with the same underlying memory? What's the point in that?

Comment: @Kametrixom in general, I want to be able to draw as many textures on a single geometry object as I want

Comment: I don't know what's preventing you from doing that, maybe it's hard to understand with your minimal explanation.

Comment: @Kametrixom I can't figure out how to make vertex/fragment shaders to accept and traverse through an array of buffers (containing textures coordinates). that is the main question. hope, it makes the problem more clear

Comment: Multiple textures are possible; Check this out: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/Render-Ctx/Render-Ctx.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014221-CH7-SW10